# Проверить содержит ли строка повторяющиеся символы подряд

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Нужно реализовать проверку, ввел ли пользователь 2 и более повторяющихся символов подряд.
На данном этапе сделал вот так:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=password]').keyup(function() {
    var pswd = $(this).val();
    if ( pswd.match(/\w*(\w)(?=\w*\1)\w*/) ) {
       $("#extraRepeatLetter").removeClass('show').addClass('none');
       extraRepeatLetter = 0;
    } else {
       $("#extraRepeatLetter").removeClass('none').addClass('show');
       extraRepeatLetter = 20;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#extraRepeatLetter p {
    display: none;
}
#extraRepeatLetter.show p {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST">
   <ul>
     <li>
        <label for="pswd">Пароль:</label>
        <span>
          <input id="pswd" type="password" name="pswd" class="password"/>
        </span>
     </li>
   </ul>
</form>
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>Пароль не содежрит повторяющихся символов</td>
     <td class="extraRepeatLetter" id="extraRepeatLetter"><p>+20</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

На данном этапе регулярка работает только с латиницей, а мне нужно что бы кирилица тоже поддерживалась, а так же не было зависимости регистра.

Пример:

- aq**s**wtyu**s** - не допустимо (у меня работает)
- aq**ы**wtyu**ы** - не допустимо (не работает)
- aq**S**wtyu**s** - не допустимо (не работает)
- aq**Ы**wtyu**ы** - не допустимо (не работает)
- aq**s**wtyu**ы** - не допустимо (не работает)
- aq**s**wtyu**Ы** - не допустимо (не работает)

Как сделать такую регулярку, что бы они прошла все тесты из примера. Желательно с обьяснениями! Спасибо

Comment: Под "символом" вы имеете в виду "букву"? Или вообще любой непробельный символ? `/(\S).*\1/.test(string)` или любой символ, `/(.).*\1/.test(string)`, не подойдёт?

Comment: Да, имеется ввиду буквы любого алфавита. Они не должны повторятся. И даже если это разные языки по типу S и Ы не должны повторятся.
В вашем примере что означает .text(string)?

Comment: Только лучше с флагом: `/(.).*\1/u.test(string)`. Чтобы было совместимее с Юникодом.

Comment: Про `.test(string)` смотрите тут: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test — это самая простая проверка, возвращающая true или false, проще чем `match()`.

Comment: Вам просто нужно не запутаться и поменять местами регулярку и строку. Было `str.match(re)` — станет `re.test(str)`.

Comment: На данном этапе я сделал вот так, но что-то не работает(
if ( /(.).*\1/u.test(pswd.string) ) {
            $("#extraRepeatLetter").removeClass('show').addClass('none');
            extraRepeatLetter = 0;
        } else {
            $("#extraRepeatLetter").removeClass('none').addClass('show');
            extraRepeatLetter = 20;
        }

Comment: Но, если не ошибаюсь, pswd у вас уже строка. Достаточно просто `/(.).*\1/u.test(pswd)`. В примерах выше `string` это просто заменитель любой переменной со строкой.

Comment: Да, если нужно игнорировать регистр, добавьте ещё один флаг: `/(.).*\1/ui.test(pswd)`.

Comment: Так почему `aqswtyuы` недопустимо, если тут нет повторов?

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь! Работают все языки, но осталось очень противное условие которое тоже хочу добавить.
Чтобы "S" и "ы" тоже считало не допустимым. Так как эти буквы находятся на одном и том же месте.

Comment: @Lisenok в одной раскладке на одном, в другой -- на другом. Лучше это программно проверять. По-моему, в регулярках это решается только перебором всех нужных сочетаний

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вот (но ваши два последние примера проходят, потому что там нет повторяющихся символов):

```
/^(?!.*(.).*\1)[a-zа-яё]*$/gim
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5bhe3

> aqswtyus
>
> aqыwtyuы
>
> aqSwtyus
>
> aqЫwtyuы
>
> **aqswtyuы**
>
> **aqswtyuЫ**
>
> **hey**
>
> hello

Comment: Та за шо минус?

Answer (score 6):

А вам обязательно регулярка? Если нужно проверить на дубликат любого символа, можно ещё так:

```js
function hasDuplicateSymbols(str) {
  return new Set(str.toLocaleLowerCase()).size !== [...str].length;
}

console.log(hasDuplicateSymbols(''));
console.log(hasDuplicateSymbols('a'));
console.log(hasDuplicateSymbols('aa'));
console.log(hasDuplicateSymbols('aA'));
console.log(hasDuplicateSymbols('Д'));
console.log(hasDuplicateSymbols('Дд'));
```

Приводим строку к нижнему регистру. Поскольку строка является итератором, её напрямую можно превратить в Set, где все дубликаты символов будут убраны. Потом размер Set-а можно сравнить с размером строки — только нужно пропустить её через spread, чтобы считались символы Юникода, а не элементы суррогатных пар, если они будут.

Если строки короткие (например, пароли), эффективность должна быть приемлемой.

Comment: С помощью регулярного выражения это не реально сделать?

Comment: Большую часть того, что вы написали я не понял. Мне просто нужно выражение с помощью которого я смогу менять местами классы. Что бы на странице показывать или скрывать елементы.

Comment: Кажется, можно. Вам в комментариях уже предложили вариант. Только добавляйте флаг Юникода, чтобы `.` отвечало символам Юникода.

Comment: Простите, если переусложнил. Если вы пока ещё не полностью освоили JS и вам проще с регулярками, пробуйте предложенное  Wiktor Stribiżew.

Comment: Вообще-то, как я понял, нужна проверка именно на буквы. В этом случае этот ответ неверен.

Comment: Ну, однозначно не было уточнено. Если речь идёт о сложности пароля, то, наверное, нет особой разницы, повторяются алфавитные символы или любые другие допустимые.